# EventMachine::HttpRequest and Keep-alive connection

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I'm using the following code to run a couple of HTTP requests, but the second request (req2) always returns to errback.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
request_options = {
  :body => " ",
  :keepalive => true,
  :head => {
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
  }
}

EM.run do
  request_options[:path] = '/default/path'

  conn = EM::HttpRequest.new 'https://www.example.com'

  req1 = conn.post request_options
  req1.errback { p 'Uh, oh'; EM.stop }
  req1.callback do
    doc = JSON.parse req1.response

    # do stuff with doc

    request_options[:body] = 'post-data'
    request_options[:path] = '/new/path'

    req2 = conn.post request_options
    req2.errback { p 'Uh, oh'; EM.stop }
    req2.callback do
       puts req2.response
       EM.stop
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A quick thing you can try is to use different copies of the `request_options` hash for the two requests. It could be that `EM::HttpRequest` is sloppy and modifies the options hash it is given (and then you pass the modified hash to your next call, thinking it's just as you set it up, when in fact it's different).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried that out, but it still returns to errback.

Comment: Too bad, would have been nice if it was that easy (but I figured it wasn't a proper answer, hence the comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by using **EM-Synchrony**

```
gem install em-synchrony
```

With this gem installed, I could use the following code to get the code work as I expected.

```
request_options = {
  :body => " ",
  :keepalive => true,
  :head => {
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
  }
}

EM.synchrony do
  request_options[:path] = '/default/path'

  conn = EM::HttpRequest.new 'https://www.example.com'

  req1 = conn.post request_options
  doc = JSON.parse req1.response

  # do stuff with doc

  request_options[:body] = 'post-data'
  request_options[:path] = '/new/path'

  req2 = conn.post request_options
  puts req2.response

  EM.stop
end
```

I guess I was just confused about they way EM.run does asynchronous requests and di.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same connection object inside the response callback.

Make sure you create a new `EM::HttpRequest.new 'https://www.example.com'` for the second request.